# Algorithm that compares elements (image files) inside the same array to find near duplicates

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, comparison

I am working on an implementation of an algorithm that, given an array of well-defined objects representing files found on a folder, should compare them in order to find duplicate-like clones for deletion. This algorithm, when finished, should account for any type of file, but to make things easier let's just talk about images for this question.

The TL;DR of this question is: what type of algorithm/rules could I implement to minimize the complexity of my big(O) notation when comparing files inside a very big array. I'm not talking about the *comparison per se* (I'm using a combination of Levenshtein / Hamming distance and Dice's Coefficient based on the 2 files being compared), but the actual decision of subdividing a million files array and applying some sort of logic behind the "processing" part of the comparison.

---

When I say that the objects are "well defined" I meant that I already have the basis of information that I can obtain on a quick scan. Things like `absolutePath`, `createDate`, `size` in bytes, `extension` and also an MD5 hash that brings everything on something that I can use as an identifier since even two identical files will at least have different dates, so the hash will be good enough. In case of images, I'm also getting the `pHash` for comparison. All of this comes *before* the actual algorithm, so nothing impacting performance yet.

The problem starts when I have a very big array with all these objects (think `arr.length > 1000000`) and all of a sudden the idiot-proof O(n log n) two for loops just doesn't cut anymore:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var fileBeingCompared = arr[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        var fileToCompare = arr[j];

        if (methodThatComparesFiles(fileBeingCompared, fileToCompare)) { // files are similar
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This actually took more than 4h on a relatively small test folder of < 10000 images, on a fairly good PC. Obviously I started to make some improvements to minimize the overhead of more than 10000^2 Levenshtein's comparisons.

In no particular order, here's what I did:

- Pre-sorted the array so that files with similar sizes would be closer together
- Spliced the array in smaller chunks and serialized their execution (with so far the same algorithm)
- Prioritize known values like `fileName` and `size` to rule out obvious duplicates before any expensive method was called
- Instead of two exact for-loops inside one another, I'm comparing strictly the not yet compared by removing the first element A from array X, comparing it with every other element B on array Y, and after that adding A to array Y. This way I dramatically reduce the number of redundant comparisons like `a = b` and `b = a` stuff. Maybe this example can illude my approach better:

```
var arrayX = []; // contains 1000 or so files
var arrayY = []; // starts empty but is filled with the already-compared elements

while (arrayX.length) {
    var fileBeingCompared = arrayX.pop();

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayY.length; i++) {
        var fileToCompare = arrayY[j];

        if (methodThatComparesFiles(fileBeingCompared, fileToCompare)) { // files are similar
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    arrayY.push(fileBeingCompared);
}
```

But even after all that, the improvements while noticeable were not nearly good enough. Not only that but the particular implementation is flawed as it is. Say I have 2 videos, one 480P, and another 1080p: every property would be different; size, name (possibly), date, etc. Since I'm currently sorting by size, they would be ending up in different threads and **not** being directly compared, leaving a duplicate.

If anyone can suggest some sort of applicable algorithm or suggestion that can help me gain performance, I'm using JS ES6 with NodeJs, so any library recommended, if any, please keep that in mind. Thank you for those who read until the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your similarity calculation has little structure, then you are going to have to test every pair. If it (or some transformation of it) at least obeys the triangle inequality, you could try building some sort of structure for answering exact or approximate nearest neighbor searches and, for each point, find its nearest neighbors. One nearest neighbor data structure that needs only distance calculations is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree, but you may see little speedup unless your points turn out mostly to live close to a low-dimensional subspace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked into those nearest neighbor implementations and it looks like it's worth a shot. My only doubt is how I could "transform" those objects that I have into a bidimensional dataset (they are usually floats) to build a tree from that. Thoughts?

Comment: The point of the cover tree is that you don't have to transform, you just need to be able to calculate distance, and that distance must be a metric. From https://hunch.net/~jl/projects/cover_tree/cover_tree.html "A Cover Tree is a datastructure helpful in calculating the nearest neighbor of points given only a metric."